# 401: Unauthorized Error Using AJAX Call - Bearer Token

Tags: javascript, ajax, azure, bearer-token

AM getting error as 401 unauthorized while calling AJAX call... When i debug error throws in setRequestHeader.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: false,
    beforeSend: function (d, c) {
        d.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + IportalauthContext.GetOauthToken(iPortal.global.common.DefaultResource))
    },
    url: b,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (c) {
        renderFooter(c.value[0], pageName);
        fOpenHeight = fOpen.outerHeight();
        $(".tOpen").css("bottom", fOpenHeight - 27);
        fOpen.addClass("fOpen");
        fOpen.removeAttr("style")
    },
    error: function (d, c) {
        console.log("Error")
    } })
```

[image]

Please provide me a suggestion or solution to track this issue.

Comment: from the image you provided it doesn't looks like your code is failing at `setRequestHeader` but is sending the request while receiving `401 unauthorized`. You can also see that your `Error` console log is printed out.

Comment: So what is the workaround solution for this

Comment: workaround? you send a request to a server and the server said you're not authorized. Maybe you a different auth token